# How to set/change input value on other div click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set/change input value on other div click? Input type is hidden.
It is possible?

Comment: could you show and explain what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you have problems with? Attaching the click event handler or setting the value? http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#your_div').on('click', function() {
  $('#hidden_input').val('some_val');
});
```

Here `your_div` points to `id` of your `div` and `hidden_input` is the `id` of hidden field. You use can any valid **[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)** for them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  $('#hiddedID').val('Some Value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div_to_click').click(function(){
  $('#hidden_input').val('input_value');
});
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/aqrvA/5/ **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/aqrvA/1/

API: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Hope this helps

**code**

```
$("#iron").click(function() {
    alert("Before Change ==> " + $("#hulk").val());
    $("#hulk").val("IRONMAN");

    alert("After Change ==> " + $("#hulk").val());
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Its no, problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div').click( function() {
        $('#input').val('value');
    });
});
```

Remember, you can work on `hidden` or `display: none` elements like they are visible.